# Rapidfire gem and undefined local variable or method when logged in (Survey creation gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to implement Rapidfire gem into my website (https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire). It all goes smoothly until i try to access the surveys with an active session, it shows this error:

```
NameError in Rapidfire/question_groups#index

Showing /home/javier/Sites/IIC2154-2013-2-Grupo1/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #31 raised:

undefined local variable or method `universities_url' for #<#<Class:0xa5728e4>:0xb4fda8cc>
```

Not only the route shown in the picture is dead but all the rest of the routes of the application. I use devise to create users and manage sessions.

Is there anyone who has used this gem or might know what might be going on?

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I go through this by setting the path instead of the variable, ex. "/universities" instead of universities_url, it's not a clean way to do it but it worked.</strike>

Edit:
After a little research I found a clean way to do this. Add main_app to the route that isn't working for that route will be main_app.universities_url

Comment: great, also if you wish to use rapidfire routes in your main app just add rapidfire isntead of main_app

Comment: I tried to do the same but the other way round by putting a rapidfire route in a main app view (rapidfire.question_groups_url) and it wont work. The error template shows: No route matches {}. Any idea?